# Remove parent node in XML Using R XML package

Tags: r, xml

How can we remove root element from a xml file using R XML library

```
<Result>
<Jobs id="1">
  <Job ID="000000" PositionID="0000">
    <Title>Development Manager - Investment Banking - Equities Business</Title>
    <Summary><![CDATA[An experienced Development Manager with previous experience leading a small to mid-size team of developers in a Java/J2EE environment. A hands on role, you will be expected to manage and mentor a team of developers working on a mix of greenfield and maintenance projects.&#160;&#160; My client, a well known investment bank, requires an experienced Development Manager to join their core technology team. This t]]></Summary>
    <DateActive Date="2009-10-06T19:36:43-05:00">10/6/2009</DateActive>
    <DateExpires Date="2009-11-05T20:11:34-05:00">11/5/2009</DateExpires>
    <DateUpdated Date="2009-10-06 20:12:00">10/6/2009</DateUpdated>
    <CompanyName>ABC Technology</CompanyName>
  </Job>
</Jobs>
</Result>
```

So, I want the output as below

```
<Jobs>
  <Job ID="000000" PositionID="0000">
    <Title>Development Manager - Investment Banking - Equities Business</Title>
    <Summary><![CDATA[An experienced Development Manager with previous experience leading a small to mid-size team of developers in a Java/J2EE environment. A hands on role, you will be expected to manage and mentor a team of developers working on a mix of greenfield and maintenance projects.&#160;&#160; My client, a well known investment bank, requires an experienced Development Manager to join their core technology team. This t]]></Summary>
    <DateActive Date="2009-10-06T19:36:43-05:00">10/6/2009</DateActive>
    <DateExpires Date="2009-11-05T20:11:34-05:00">11/5/2009</DateExpires>
    <DateUpdated Date="2009-10-06 20:12:00">10/6/2009</DateUpdated>
    <CompanyName>ABC Technology</CompanyName>
  </Job>
</Jobs>
```

So, No more

```
<Result></Result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select the needed node by XPath then save to file with `saveXML`. Below show equivalent calls:

```
newdoc <- xpathApply(doc, "/Result/Jobs")  # OR getNodeSet(doc, "/Result/Jobs")
newdoc
# [[1]]
# <Jobs id="1">
#   <Job ID="000000" PositionID="0000">
#     <Title>Development Manager - Investment Banking - Equities Business</Title>
#     <Summary><![CDATA[An experienced Development Manager with previous experience leading a small to mid-size team of developers in a Java/J2EE environment. A hands on role, you will be expected to manage and mentor a team of developers working on a mix of greenfield and maintenance projects.&#160;&#160; My client, a well known investment bank, requires an experienced Development Manager to join their core technology team. This t]]>  </Summary>
#     <DateActive Date="2009-10-06T19:36:43-05:00">10/6/2009</DateActive>
#     <DateExpires Date="2009-11-05T20:11:34-05:00">11/5/2009</DateExpires>
#     <DateUpdated Date="2009-10-06 20:12:00">10/6/2009</DateUpdated>
#     <CompanyName>ABC Technology</CompanyName>
#   </Job>
# </Jobs> 

# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLNodeSet"

saveXML(newdoc[[1]], file="Output.xml")
```

To remove the top level attributes, run below prior to saving:

```
removeAttributes(newdoc[[1]])
```

Comment: i was trying to do it with removeNodes could not succeed since 2 hours. your solution is simple enough.