# Removing parent nodes from xml file in r

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I have xml output below. I am trying to remove parents using XML or xml2 library from R. I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893713/remove-parent-node-in-xml-using-r-xml-package) but those functions somehow gave me an error. I am trying to remove those parents until `analysisdata` parent. That is what I am going to parse.

```
<assessment>
  <itembank />
  <instrument id="797393  ">
    <form id="Math G3">
      <formitem id="8243" position="0" />

    </form>
  </instrument>
  <admin id="797393  " instrument="797393  ">
    <genatt name="adminperiod" value="SP19" />
    <responseanalyses>
      <responsebankref id="3M" />
      <analysisdefs>
        <analysisoption name="mark" value="no" />
        <analysisoption name="notreached" value="ASNOTPRESENTED" />
        <statentity type="item" id="8243" varname="I_8243">
          <genatt name="type" value="CR" />
          <genatt name="codestart" value="0" />
          <genatt name="validcodes" value="2" />
          <genatt name="omitcode" value="9" />
          <genatt name="notpresentedcode" value="8" />
          <statentity code="0.000000" id="0.000000" type="itemscorept" />
          <statentity code="1.000000" id="1.000000" type="itemscorept" />
          <statentity code="9" id="omit" type="itemscorept" />
        </statentity>

          <genatt name="type" value="CR" />
          <genatt name="codestart" value="0" />
          <genatt name="validcodes" value="2" />
          <genatt name="omitcode" value="9" />
          <genatt name="notpresentedcode" value="8" />
          <statentity code="0.000000" id="0.000000" type="itemscorept" />
          <statentity code="1.000000" id="1.000000" type="itemscorept" />
          <statentity code="9" id="omit" type="itemscorept" />
        </statentity>
        <statentity id="DIFGROUP_TTS" varname="DIFGROUP_TTS" type="popgroup" description="DIFGROUP_TTS">
          <statentity code="0.000000" id="0.000000" description="0.000000" samplesize="40501" type="popsubgroup" />
          <statentity code="1.000000" id="1.000000" description="1.000000" samplesize="5532" type="popsubgroup" />
        </statentity>

      </analysisdefs>
      <genatt name="xmloutputfile" value="J:\out.xml" />
      <analysis creator="ST" description="" level="form" type="classical">
    <analysisdata formid="Math G3">

          <statentityref id="8243" type="item">
            <statval type="OmitCount" value="0.000000" />
            <statval type="NotReachedCount" value="43.000000" />
            <statval type="PolyserialCorrelation" value="0.644181" />
            <statval type="AdjustedPolyserial" value="0.644181" />
            <statval type="AverageScore" value="0.223074" se="0.011957" />
            <statval type="NCount" value="2609.000000" />
            <statval type="StdevItemScore" value="0.416308" />
              </statentityref>

            </statentityref>
          </statentityref>
        </analysisdata>
      </analysis>
    </responseanalyses>
    <responsebank findin="J:\outAM.am" sourcetype="AM" id="3M" />
  </admin>
</assessment>
```

I tried 
library(xml2)
library(XML)
`newdoc <- xpathApply(doc, "/assessment/admin/responseanalyses")` I get this error after running this: `Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"`. THis solution was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893713/remove-parent-node-in-xml-using-r-xml-package).

After removing those parent nodes, I would like to have `analysisdata` node only after removing the assessment/admin/responseanalyses parent node. Desired out is like this below:

```
<analysisdata formid="Math G3">
  <statentityref id="8243" type="item">
    <statval type="OmitCount" value="0.000000" />
    <statval type="NotReachedCount" value="43.000000" />
    <statval type="PolyserialCorrelation" value="0.644181" />
    <statval type="AdjustedPolyserial" value="0.644181" />
    <statval type="AverageScore" value="0.223074" se="0.011957" />
    <statval type="NCount" value="2609.000000" />
    <statval type="StdevItemScore" value="0.416308" />
      </statentityref>

    </statentityref>
  </statentityref>
</analysisdata>
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Just extract the node. Eg `rvest::html_node(doc, 'analysisdata')`

Comment: This is my answer. Thanks for your suggestion :) If you post this, I will accept as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `html_node` from `rvest` library

```
 rvest::html_node(doc, 'analysisdata')
```